# Find word which contains a specified group of letters REGEXP

Tags: php, regex

I want to find all the words that contain a specified group of letters, for example if I want to search the with the group of letter ph int the text `phone find phill phdas` I want the REGEXP to return me `phill phone phdas` I dont want to do it in another way than REGEXP. (PHP)

Comment: All your answers are good , but if i want to check for multiple groups of letters i should do like this /\w*(ph|in)\w*/  and when i print_R my output id does not show me the word, just the group of letters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/\w*ph\w*/
```

That will match 0 or more word characters, followed by your search term `ph`, followed by 0 or more word characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mvHu9A/1)

**PHP Code:**

```
$kw = 'ph';
preg_match_all('/\w*' . $kw . '\w*/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: You should change `\w` to `\S` IMO to be able to match non alphanumeric words with special characters too. But as the question is not very specific about "words" this would also do it.

Comment: @anubhava Thx for your answer, check my comment please and help me with it if you can .

Comment: Just use: `/\w*(?:ph|in)\w*/` in `preg_match_all` and then `print_r($matches[0]);`

Comment: @anubhava tahnks for help man! I have voted the answer as the right one !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pregmatch function of php and as it's first argument give the regex as /\w*ph\w*/. Give stars after the w as well , that is for any character present..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $subject = "your subject";
  $pattern = '//\w*ph\w*//';
  preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
  print_r($matches);
?>
```